# Textbox ghosting when switching routes

Tags: angularjs

I've been playing around with AngularJs a little bit and I've been having some issues on textboxes flickering when changing routes in Chrome. Below are some screenshots that I took:

[image: before route change]

[image: after route change]

Have any of you been able to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out a work-around to the problem. I used $window.location.assign instead of $location.url. The full page reload seemed to have solved the ghosting issue of text boxes when doing route changes between different views in Chrome.